# Windows backup reports wrong free space if done to a network drive?

Tags: windows-7, backup, network-drive

We use Windows 7 SP1 built-in back up to a network drive and today I have discovered a strange behavior: the free space reported directly in the backup window did not change after we deleted some old back-ups. However, the space reported in the "Manage space" window seemed to be more correct.

[image: Free space reported by backup is wrong]

Is it just a problem with free space indication or something more serious? Can it impede the next scheduled backup?

Comment: just to clarify, in your local culture, is it common to use commas to seperate whole numbers from decimal values? just wondering if the numbers are correctly formatted for your locality.

Comment: @FrankThomas: [This list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma) includes Germany.

Comment: Perhaps for performance reasons the free space is queried only when "Manage space" is clicked? Does closing the app and reopening it update the first value?

Comment: @Karan: No, the reopening of the window and even newstart (!) do not update the values. The free space seems to be reported this way by the network share...